# Translating Delphi VarSupports to C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, ihtmldocument2

I am attempting to translate this code from Delphi to C++ Builder:

```pascal
 procedure HandleStyleSheets(const Document: IDispatch);
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;                      // document object
  StyleSheets: IHTMLStyleSheetsCollection;  // document's style sheets
  SheetIdx: Integer;                        // loops thru style sheets
  OVSheetIdx: OleVariant;                   // index of a style sheet
  StyleSheet: IHTMLStyleSheet;              // reference to a style sheet
  OVStyleSheet: OleVariant;                 // variant ref to style sheet
  RuleIdx: Integer;                         // loops thru style sheet rules
  Style: IHTMLRuleStyle;                    // ref to rule's style
begin
   // Get IHTMLDocument2 interface of document
  if not Supports(Document, IHTMLDocument2, Doc) then
Exit;
  // Loop through all style sheets
  StyleSheets := Doc.styleSheets;
  for SheetIdx := 0 to Pred(StyleSheets.length) do
  begin
   OVSheetIdx := SheetIdx; // sheet index as variant required for next call
   // Get reference to style sheet (comes as variant which we convert to
   // interface reference)
   OVStyleSheet := StyleSheets.item(OVSheetIdx);
 if VarSupports(OVStyleSheet, IHTMLStyleSheet, StyleSheet) then
 begin
   // Loop through all rules within style a sheet
   for RuleIdx := 0 to Pred(StyleSheet.rules.length) do
   begin
     // Get style from a rule and reset required attributes.
     // Note: style is IHTMLRuleStyle, not IHTMLStyle, although many
     // attributes are shared between these interfaces
     Style := StyleSheet.rules.item(RuleIdx).style;
     Style.backgroundImage := '';  // removes any background image
     Style.backgroundColor := '';  // resets background colour to default
     end;
   end;
  end;
end;
```

Everything went fine until this line:

```
    if (VarSupports(OVStyleSheet, IID_IHTMLStyleSheet, StyleSheet))
```

It reports: E2285 Could not find a match for 'VarSupports(OleVariant,_GUID,_di_IHTMLStyleSheet)'

Everything else translated just fine. Can anyone help me with above line?

My translation so far:

```c
DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> Doc;                                        // document object
DelphiInterface<IHTMLStyleSheetsCollection> StyleSheets;                    // document's style sheets
int SheetIdx;                                                               // loops thru style sheets
OleVariant OVSheetIdx;                                                      // index of a style sheet
DelphiInterface<IHTMLStyleSheet> StyleSheet;                                // reference to a style sheet
OleVariant OVStyleSheet;                                                    // variant ref to style sheet
int RuleIdx;                                                                // loops thru style sheet rules
DelphiInterface<IHTMLRuleStyle> Style;                                      // ref to rule's style
DelphiInterface<IHTMLStyleSheetRule> StyleSheetRule;

// Get IHTMLDocument2 interface of document
if (!Supports(EmbeddedWB1->Document, IID_IHTMLDocument2, Doc)) throw Exception("Not supported");

// Loop through all style sheets
StyleSheets = Doc->styleSheets;
for (SheetIdx = 0; SheetIdx < StyleSheets->length; SheetIdx++)
    {
    OVSheetIdx = SheetIdx;                                                  // sheet index as variant required for next call
    // Get reference to style sheet (comes as variant which we convert to  interface reference)
    StyleSheets->item(OVSheetIdx, OVStyleSheet);
    if (VarSupports(OVStyleSheet, IID_IHTMLStyleSheet, StyleSheet))
        {
        // Loop through all rules within style a sheet
        for (RuleIdx = 0; RuleIdx < StyleSheet->rules->length; RuleIdx)
            {
            // Get style from a rule and reset required attributes.
            // Note: style is IHTMLRuleStyle, not IHTMLStyle, although many
            // attributes are shared between these interfaces

            StyleSheet->rules->item(RuleIdx, StyleSheetRule);
            Style = StyleSheetRule->style;

            Style->backgroundImage = L"";  // removes any background image
            Style->backgroundColor = L"";  // resets background colour to default
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the compile error is that VarSupports is defined as taking a `Variant`, and you are passing an `OleVariant`.

It looks to me as if the code is trying to assign the `OVStyleSheet` to the `IHTMLStyleSheet` interface StyleSheet.  In C++ Builder, you should be able to just assign it, as in

```
_di_IInterface inter = _di_IInterface(OVStyleSheet);
StyleSheet = inter;
```

If that succeeds and `StyleSheet` is not NULL, you should be able to use `StyleSheet`.  Note that invalid Variant assignments can throw an exception, so you might want to handle that (and assume that the exception also means that the `OVStyleSheet` does not support the `IHTMLStyleSheet` interface)

Also, C++ Builder has an Interface.Supports function that appears to do what VarSupports does,  except that VarSupports takes a variant, so Interface.Supports also requires you to obtain the interface from the OleVariant yourself.  Probably something like:

```
di_IInterface inter = _di_IInterface(OVStyleSheet);
if (inter->Supports(StyleSheet))
{
    ShowMessage("StyleSheet has been assigned");
}
```

This compiles, but I have not tested it.

Comment: Thanks but if I assign it like that it cannot compile - E2285 Could not find a match for 'operator _di_IHTMLStyleSheet::= <ANOTHERINTF>(OleVariant)'

Comment: You do have to obtain the interface from the OleVariant first -- I have corrected the code above.  As noted, it compiles, but I have not functionally tested it.